# Navigator observer observe push event when open dialog

Tags: flutter, navigation

In this case I want to add willpopscope to my app,and I found that sometimes it is not able to pop correctly,so I debug the code and I found observer observe push event when open dialog,I think it is strange.

This is my observer

```
class MyNavigatorObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  List<Route<dynamic>> routeStack = List();

  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    previous = previousRoute;
    current = route;
    routeStack?.add(route);
    print('didPush');
    print(routeStack.length);
    print(routeStack.sublist(0));
  }

  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    if (routeStack.length > 0) {
      routeStack?.removeLast();
      print('didPop');
      print(routeStack.length);
      print(routeStack.sublist(0));
    }
  }

  @override
  void didRemove(Route route, Route previousRoute) {
    routeStack?.removeLast();
  }

  @override
  void didReplace({Route newRoute, Route oldRoute}) {
    routeStack?.removeLast();
    routeStack?.add(newRoute);
  }
}
```

and I use it at the main class of app's page

```
WillPopScope(
          ...
        child: Navigator(
          observers: [MyNavigatorObserver],
          key: _navigator,
          onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
             ...
          }
          ...
          if (page.parentRoute != null) {
            return MaterialPageRoute(
            ...
           );
          } else {
          NaviArguments arg = settings.arguments;
           return PageRouteBuilder(
            ...
          );
       }
     },
   ),
 ),
```

and when I trigger an action to show dialog

```
void showProfileChildView(
  BuildContext context, {
  ProfileChildBuilder child,
  ProfileViewState state,
}) {
  showGeneralDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
    pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, _) {
      var scaleAnimation = Tween(
        begin: Offset(0.0, 1.0),
        end: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
      ).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeOutExpo)).animate(animation);
      return SlideTransition(
        position: scaleAnimation,
        child: ProfileChildView(
          child: child,
          profileViewState: state,
        ),
      );
    },
    useRootNavigator: false,
  );
}
```

it prints out this

```
I/flutter (25147): didPush
I/flutter (25147): 1
I/flutter (25147): [_DialogRoute<dynamic>(RouteSettings("null", null), animation: AnimationController#48fc4(▶ 0.000; for _DialogRoute<dynamic>))]
```

In other cases when I trigger other dialog(not full-page) it won't trigger the push event
Is it because one is full-page one is not full-page?
can someone tell me why?

Comment: how/where you use your `MyNavigatorObserver`? in `MatrialApp.navigatorObservers`?

Comment: in WillPopScope->Navigator

Comment: sorry, i have no idea how `NavigatorObserver` can be used with `WillPopScope` widget - it takes only `child` and `onWillPop` parameters

Comment: i update the post is that clear?please tell me

Comment: i tried `MatrialApp.navigatorObservers` and it shows any kind of dialog when it appears/disappears

Comment: so normally it can observer the dialog whether  it's showDialog or showGeneralDialog?

Comment: I used showDialog which uses showGeneralDialog under the hood

Comment: oh yes, showDialog is a package of showGeneralDialog, but I wonder why it's not added to the MyNavigatorObserver.routeStack  when it appears/disappears

Comment: why dont you use `MatrialApp.navigatorObservers `?

Comment: I will try that out, thanks